# making a list from the users answer

Tags: python, exception, user-input, infinite-loop, puzzle

I am working on a project where I have to generate a puzzle based on the users input. I would ask the user how many words they will want to include in the puzzle and will also ask for the word. However, the puzzle must work with 4-9 words and each word must be at least 9 letters long. I already wrote some code to start off with since I'm doing it in pieces (I'm new to python) but my code does not stop asking the user for more words, it just keeps asking. If the user says they want only 4 words, and once they enter the 4 words, it should stop there but my code still keeps asking for more words. Any guidance is appreciated! I have 2 python files. one named "main.py" and the other one named "puzzler.py" in my main.py I have this code:

```
import puzzler
changeable_grid = list()

ways = 0
word_list = []

# TODO:
# 1A. ask user to input how many words they wanna work with
def ask_num_words() -> int:
    global num_of_words
    while True:
        try:
            num_of_words = int(input('How many words would you want to work with: '))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        if puzzler.MIN_WORD <= num_of_words <= puzzler.MAX_WORD:
            break
        else:
            print('Sorry words can only be between {} and {}'.format(puzzler.MIN_WORD, puzzler.MAX_WORD))
            print('')
            continue
    return num_of_words

# 1B. ask user to input the words for the puzzle
    def ask_for_words(amt_of_words: int) -> list:
        global word
        while True:
            try:
                for i in range(amt_of_words):
                    word = input('Please enter the word: ')
                    word_length = len(word)
                    if puzzler.MIN_WORD_LENGTH >= word_length or word_length >= puzzler.MAX_WORD_LENGTH:
                        print('The word must be be between {} and {} in length'.format(puzzler.MIN_WORD_LENGTH,
                                                                                       puzzler.MAX_WORD_LENGTH))
                        print('')
                        word = input('Re-enter the word again:')
                        word_length = len(word)
                word_list.append(word)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
        print(word_list)
        return word_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    amt_of_words = ask_num_words()
    ask_for_words(amt_of_words
```

)

In my puzzler.py file so far I only have this code:

```
MAX_WORD = 9
MIN_WORD = 4
MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 9
MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use "while True:" when you want something to happen forever.I think you should just take it out from ask_for_words.